# How to formalize substitutions in generating functions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, generating-functions, formal-power-series

In my linear algebra course we recently defined generating functions as elements of the ring $R[[x]]$ formal power series over a Ring $R$. If you consider $x$ to be a formal power series corresponding to the sequence $(0, 1, 0, 0,\dots)$ you can take the inverse (in $R[[x]]^\times$) of $1+x$ and show it to be

$$\frac1{1+x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k x^k \tag{1}$$

From this we wanted to derive, by substituting $x \to -x$ that

$$\frac1{1-x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k \tag{2}$$

Intuitively this should work and its easy to prove, that $1/(1-x)$ is the generating function of the series in $(2)$. However I'm not really sure how I should interpret this substitution (or other substitution like $x \to x^2$) in a rigorous way.

So my question is how would you formalize the deduction $(1) \Rightarrow (2)$ and more generally proofs using substitution in generating functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a ring homomorphism $\phi: R[X] \to R[X]$ given by $X \mapsto -X$. This isomorphism takes $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k x^k$ and outputs $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k$.

You've shown already that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k x^k \times (1+x) = 1$; so this holds when you apply $\phi$, yielding $\phi(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k x^k) \times \phi(1+x) = 1$. That is, $\phi(\frac{1}{1+x}) = \frac{1}{1-x}$. The left-hand side is just $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k$.

Comment: how do you argue that $\phi\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k x^k \right) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k$ ?

Comment: By definition of a homomorphism. The left-hand side is $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \phi((-1)^k X^k)$, but $\phi((-1)^k X^k) = (-1)^k \phi(X)^k = (-1)^k (-1)^k X^k$.

Comment: But what allows you to swap $\phi$ and the *infinite* sum?

Comment: Did you mean $R[[X]]$?

Comment: @0x539, a *formal* power series isn't an infinite sum.

Comment: @0x539 That's just what a homomorphism is on the ring of formal power series.

Comment: @PatrickStevens I'm so sure, after all the definition only guarantees that $\phi(f+g) = \phi(f) + \phi(g)$. The interchangeability of $\phi$ and finite sums can be easily shown by induction, but the case of an "inifite sum" isn't trivial to me.